# Is it possible to discover / analyze the properties of alloys (or other man-made materials) purely theoretically?

Tags: temperature, material-science, models

I know that it is possible to model heat dissipation in a material w/ CAD. It is also possible to model fluid flow. But is it for example, possible to model Kanthal's behavior in different circumstances (magnetic fields, temperatures) theoretically (via equations or via a CAD application)?

For example: the usual composition of kenthal is iron, chromium (20–30%) and aluminium (4–7.5 %). Let say it has property set Xp under circumstances Xc. Is there a way to for example to predict Xp in Xc for an alloy with more alluminum w/o experimentation i.e. theoretically?

Comment: One can analyze many material properties theoretically- the hard part is actually getting them right.

Comment: Can you expand on this thought? Is it possible to increase the amount of one material in an alloy and calculate precisely how the  resistivity, heat disipation and other properties would change?

Answer (score 1):

Practical answer : No.

If you do not know the equations which describe how the various parameters affect each other, then you cannot make a prediction. CAD works for heat and fluid flows because all of the relationships (ie equations) are known and are built into the model.

It is possible to build a theoretical model of the properties of bulk material, but this is extremely difficult. The properties of an alloy are not usually the weighted average of those of its constituents. Properties like resistance often depend on structural features, such as dislocations in the crystal. As the relative numbers of atoms is changed, the structure of the material can also change, leading to different properties from those expected. Structure can also differ depending on how the material was manufactured.

Comment: Thank you. Are there any situations where properties of an alloy ARE the weighted average of those of its constituents and is that equivalent to saying that "properties are independent from the internal structure of the material". Can linear changes in the proportions of quantities of the constituents of the material  produce non-linear changes in the properties like resistivity? Are there any good examples where adding a bit of some material would drastically change the properties of the medium?

Comment: You are asking a lot of additional questions. The Q&A format is suitable for single questions which can be answered in at most a few paragraphs. If you wish to learn about a whole topic then you need to read a book on the subject. I am not a metallurgist so I don't know what to recommend. The answers for alloys are difficult enough. Asking about "other man-made materials" is far too broad and difficult a question.